# Upload a File in Server in Target Path using HTTPClient 4

Tags: java, upload, httpclient

I want to upload a file using HTTPClient jar.
Where i can mention the target path in the destination server
to which the file should be uploade.

In HTTPClient 3.1 the target path can be mentioned in MultiPartPost constructor
method  but in HTTPCLient 4 this class is removed.

Thanks
SHyam

Answer (score 0):

Does the multipart POST sample [ClientMultipartFormPost.java](https://github.com/apache/httpcomponents-client/blob/master/httpclient5/src/test/java/org/apache/hc/client5/http/examples/ClientMultipartFormPost.java) help ?